# Possible bug in the search

Tags: bug, search

That's the snapshot of my screen when I encountered this bug. I encountered this bug couple of times. For the first few times I thought there might be some maintenance going on. But it happened to me again. I know its not possible because this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) is the top result on that page. So is this a bug?

[image: Snapshot]