# Penalty for answering help-vampire questions? Or reward closure?

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts, help-vampire

In [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), I often come across answers from a certain user on typical help vampire questions.

Questions that *should* be closed as duplicates, instead of being answered. You know the type: *No* research done, *no* attempts made at solving the problem, and the problem itself is something that can be solved by opening the first result on a google search for the question's title.
Basically, questions of such blatantly low quality, it takes more effort to write a short answer than to close it as duplicate.

Yet, some users insist on *answering* those questions, even though they're in possession of a gold badge in the related tag. (And can close obvious dupes with ease.)

Sure, a large portion of those questions will eventually be closed, and with some luck, deleted, but answers on questions that aren't deleted will still award rep to the help-vampire vampire. Rep they usually get from the answer being upvoted (even just once) / accepted. The quantity of answers on these low quality questions eventually adds up...

**Is there anything we can do to further discourage (experienced) users from answering un-salvageable questions, or to encourage those users to close-vote them instead?**
Meaning questions that should / will be closed within, say, an hour of being posted.

I've got a couple of ideas:

*"Punishments"*:

- A rep penalty for answering questions that are closed as dupe within a short time span after posting.
  Say, if a question is closed as dupe within 30 minutes of it being asked, a answer most likely wasn't the way to go.
  The rep penalty could be a set penalty, or the votes on the answer (including accept vote) could no longer count for the user's rep. The set penalty has the (arguable) disadvantage that upvotes could outweigh it.
- A answer ban / throttle when a large portion of a user's answers end up being deleted (optionally: due to question deletion).
- Restrict a user from answering questions posted by low rep users, if a large portion of their answers is deleted.
  A bit unorthodox, but a majority of the the help-vampire questions are posted by low rep users. If those questions *can't* be answered by people found "guilty" of answering low quality questions, too much... I'm not sure how users like this could be identified, and once they are, can work to have this status removed.

*"Rewards"*:

- Award rep to users participating in a close-vote
  This has some risks. The reward can't be too high, or users will blindly close-vote. The rep should obviously be lost if the question is re-opened. Gold badge owners shouldn't get too tempted to grind rep this way (no idea how, though).
- Allow the OP of the question to immediately validate the dupe vote, maybe even linking some kind of reward to that.
  Just like suggested edits can immediately be accepted, it may be a good idea to allow dupe voted to be accepted by the OP

<sup>(These are simply suggestions, could well be that this wouldn't work for some reason)</sup>

I realize that some of these suggestions will only "punish" one side of the help-vampire problem.
I think it's more efficient to educate frequent visitors like this. New users will always keep asking without reading the rules / researching, and new users will keep coming to SO.

**To be clear**:

My intention with this post is to find a method to persuade *experienced users* to close-vote as duplicate, instead of answering.
The main problem is that users that know the site very well, still answer obvious duplicates, or easy, extremely low quality questions, just to get rep.

Comment: I'm curious what ideas you guys can come up with, and what flaws there could be with my suggestions. I'd say, open fire!

Comment: I like the motivation, but I feel that the ideas are still rather flawed. The dupe closing process is not perfect and can be disputed, and since gold badge user can be vampire helper themselves, it's not effective. Answer throttling may work based on answer deleted along with question depends on how frequent the question is deleted (which varies based on the number of serious people in each tag).

Comment: Thanks for the feeback. Yea, the ideas are just some quick-and-dirty suggestions I thought up. Personally, I've yet to see a dupe vote disputed by a vampire helper. I don't know how often questions / answers are deleted. That'd have to be investigated...

Comment: I get the desired results, but I have problems with the conclusions drawn here. Yes help vampirism is a problem, but this question seems to be more about "vampires of help vampires" - something I don't think is really a thing. Isn't that just either basic rep whoring, paired with the large pile of people who are out to use SO as a social gathering and thus answer any and all questions to be nice?

Comment: @Gimby: I've seen a user specifically answer those low quality, easy to answer posts. I've mjolnir'd at least half a dozen of the questions that specific user answered on, this (work-)week alone. It's not like I'm searching for questions answered by him. This user has some great answers, sure, but a lot of his answers are mediocre quick answers on even worse questions that should've been closed in the first place, just for the rep.

Comment: @Cerbrus, if I'm not mistaken you left a comment to that user (roughly) two hours ago, and they subsequently deleted their answer. Maybe they understood the message? Do you have reasons to believe further action should be taken?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I've made that same comment half a dozen times before. I don't think he's following my suggestion.

Comment: `Personally, I've yet to see a dupe vote disputed by a vampire helper.` Don't know, but it might become a war between gold badge users once reputation is involved. The positive side is that the number of crap questions is reduced, but the negative side is that the questions might be closed dup incorrectly. `I don't know how often questions / answers are deleted.` In regex tag, it's rare. Only the no attempt ones are closed, leaving a bunch of bad questions about topics which are not useful to anyone aside from OP (match HTML/XML/JSON with regex, for example).

Comment: @Cerbrus, to that same user? Well, thanks for the information, now I know not to waste my time trying to curb their behavior in the future. And indeed, maybe something else must be done.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Yes, that exact same user. Frankly, he's the "inspiration" for this suggestion. If his answers were all high quality, it may not be that big of a problem, but often enough, the answers are, well, crap.

Comment: @Cerbrus So maybe this should be about doing something about that one user.

Comment: @Cerbrus, they're pretty representative of the problem. AFAICT nearly the entirety of their 200K+ rep comes from providing short answers to bad questions (they did drop the "try this" a while ago, though, and started to post "better" answers). It would be nice if we could put a system in place to prevent users from accumulating that much rep that way.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: That's exactly what my suggestion is about. The user isn't contributing with quality answers. (Sure, he has some great answers, but most of it gets just 1 upvote from the OP)

Comment: @Gimby: Possibly, but I'm not going to call him out on a meta post.

Comment: related: [What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262077/839601) Dupes, meet roomba: "we dispense with the logic that preserves answers with 1 vote or an accept mark that will stay deletion at 9 days. Downvoted duplicates are also added to the mix..."

Comment: I don't see much of a problem with *new* users answering low quality/help-vampire/rep-whorish questions. After all, everyone needs to start *somewhere*. Asking new users to sit around for a long time waiting for a "good question" to show up is more likely to turn the user away from SO than to result in an answer being posted. (remember 90%+ of the questions on SO are crap) And when a good question *does* show up there's often so many people jumping on them (FGITW) that they can't possibly "win". What *does* bother me are high-rep users that never grew out of answering the easy stuff.

Comment: @Mysticial, so we're in agreement here. Let new users answer whatever they want, but expect high-rep users to conform to higher standards. Now the question is: can we *enforce* that? Should we? How could we do that in our usual, consensual, argumented kind of way?

Comment: We should all have a stake in this.

Comment: @Cerbrus The user you're talking about seems to be the fastest gun as well... I suspect that the quality of answers and the frequency of answering dups has a strong relation to how fast they're being produced.

Comment: [Stop the gamers: neutralize rep earned on answers to questions closed within 24 hours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214426) [Should there be a deterrent for answering obvious duplicate questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252009) [Should we discourage answers to low quality questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239059) [Cause some closed questions to not grant answer rep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203879) See also [Feeders, not help vampires, are the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86308)

Comment: If the question should be closed as a duplicate, is it really a "help vampire" situation? it's not always easy to find duplicates, much less an answer to a question when you may not know the proper terms to search by. It's easy to find a duplicate of a question if you already know the answer.

Comment: If the question should be closed as a duplicate, it's more likely to be a help vampire situation. Since those questions often lack research from the OP's side.

Comment: This question is more of a rant than anything else. It isn't posed well enough to seek input from the community and is heavily biased.

Comment: @TravisJ: So far I've gotten plenty of input, as well as some good ideas on how this problem could be handled. Sure, it's a bit of a rant, and it's biased, but that doesn't mean this question no longer merits any discussion. Frankly, that comment isn't very constructive.

Comment: 4 _"This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community."_ close votes. Please read the question before posting. I've edited the question a bit to _emphasize_ the opportunity for input that was already in there...

Comment: @Cerbus - Let's be honest, this question identifies itself as a "public warning message", *To be clear: My intention with this post is to persuade experienced users* you sign off with. You start with a perceived gripe against another user. This is fully a rant, and is barely defined as evidenced by the inclusion of both the discussion *and* feature-request tags. Further, the topic of dissuading users from answering has been covered in the past multiple times and the resounding response is **no, we should not discourage answers**. I don't see anything else here, and that is why I voted to close

Comment: I like to call those types of answerers "Cherry pickers".   Answering super-easy questions to get rep points rather than linking to a dupe, or posting a comment that will guide the vampire to find their own answer.  I wouldn't go so far as to punish the cherry picker, but I would like to see them not get rewarded either.  However, I have no solid idea for a good way to put this into effect.

Comment: Regardless of the intention, this suggestion goes against the site's architecture, which is to reward users for answering questions. The site makes no attempt to punish users automatically for answering questions. All penalties incurred on the site (just like nearly all benefits), by design, come from community interaction of *users*.

Comment: I've added a bit to the question. I'm not the best writer, I'll be the first to admit that (Heck, English ain't even my native language). However, my intention with this post was _always_ to get _as much feedback as possible._ Sure, this may be a bit of a rant, but that doesn't mean the problem doesn't exist, nor does that make it impossible to discuss this issue.

Comment: "Allow the OP of the question to immediately validate the dupe vote".  Doesn't this already exist as the "that solved my problem" button?

Comment: @ryanyuyu: No idea, I've never seen a question closed after less than 5 close-votes (Mjölnir / mods excluded).

Comment: @Cerbrus It's in effect, and [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298668/possible-bug-in-the-search) was actually closed by that process. I flagged it, the OP agreed and hit the button to say so, Community auto-closed it.

Comment: @Kendra: Hm, users on SO seem to be reluctant to accept dupe votes then. Does this also work for other closure reasons? (Should it?)

Comment: It only works for duplicates at the moment. Naturally, a lot of newer users who don't understand the site are probably very likely to argue that because their code is ever so slightly different, the questions aren't duplicates. That's likely why I've seen it more on meta: Less 'new' users and more who understand the system a bit. Should this work for other close reasons? I doubt it would work. If your question is flagged as too broad, and you're a new user, how likely are you going to be to agree it's too broad? (Just as an example.)

Comment: Good point, @Kendra. I agree that new users are unlikely to accept other close votes... Still, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: And *this question* was closed-as-dupe! It is to laugh..!

Comment: It took 6 days to get closed. It got the attention it needed to get closed only after I posted a link to this question on a different similar question. I'd hardly call this an obvious duplicate. I'm not saying the close-vote is incorrect, just that this isn't an example of the problem described in the question.

Answer (score 38):

One solution would be to simply remove any Imaginary Internet Points gained from answering questions that are subsequently closed.

The following conditions should apply to this solution,

- Previously used reasoning be used, for example:

> First, if you've contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets deleted. "Worthwhile" here is defined as,
>
> - A score of 3 or greater
> - Visible on the site for at least 60 days
>
> <sub>**From:** [Reputation and Historical Archives](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)</sub>

- **This would exclude duplicate questions.** Duplicates are good signposts, so should be left alone. **You would still gain rep from questions marked as a duplicate.**
- **But my answer was really good!** If a question is reopened then the rep would be re-applied, edit the question into shape and get it reopened!
  **But the question is not salvageable!** Feel free to post your good answer on a more deserving question.
- **No reputation should be lost in the making of this solution.** This should not apply to any already closed questions, just questions closed after this is instituted.

**This would not punish anyone.** Users would not be rewarded for answering bad questions and it would hopefully encourage users to do the following,

- Request better clarifications before answering.
- (Suggest an) edit the question to make it adhere to the guidelines.
- Vote to close if applicable.
- Vote to reopen ***if*** applicable.

There would be no plus-side to answering bad questions unless you edit the questions into shape or encourage the author of the question to do so. Those answering the bad questions would hopefully join the fight for better questions and start moderating the questions they would have previously answered.

---

In the case that users 3k+ would simply try to reopen the question without editing it into shape first, they would have to convince four other users that it is not off-topic / unclear. Users only have one close and one reopen vote for each question, so when the question is inevitably closed again the same users won't be able to vote to reopen again. The answerer would have to convince another five users to vote to reopen.

This already happens, though hopefully not often, and the usual suggested solution is to just allow the war to run its course and it will either end up open because it is a good question or closed because it is not. Sometimes it may end up in the wrong state for the wrong reason, but we hope this doesn't happen and if it does then we hope some user will find it someday and (solicit) votes to close or reopen accordingly.

---

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/337288/my-answers-to-bad-questions) will show you answers that you have posted to questions which should not have been answered according to the current closure reasons, and some information about those answers.

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/337355/reputation-i-have-gained-from-answers-to-bad-qestions) will show you the estimated Imaginary Internet Points you have gained from answers posted to questions which should not have been answered according to the current closure reasons.

These queries are not completely accurate because they do not take into account the following,

- Reputation Cap
- Questions that predate their close reason
- `[on hold]` questions.

Not taking into account the above as well as other possibly unseen caveats,

- Approximately [17,545,735 Imaginary Internet Points](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/337478/reputation-i-have-gained-from-answers-to-bad-qestions) have been earned on the site as a whole from answering question that are now considered bad questions.
- Approximately [532,779 answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/337478/how-many-answers-to-bad-questions-are-there) have been posted to questions that are now considered bad questions.

Again the above queries are probably pretty naive and are most likely not taking some things into account, but it is somewhat representative of the real total.

---

Please feel free to edit this solution if you think that you can clarify or the queries above if you can include what is not taken into account above.

Thanks to shog9 for the edits to the above queries.

Comment: Such a simple solution. I like the idea.

Comment: [This is never going to happen.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149778/should-closed-questions-not-award-reputation-to-discourage-asking-poor-questions)

Comment: @durron597 That's a discussion from 2012. Things change.

Comment: How would this handle popular questions that were closed 5 years in the future because the community felt they were no longer on topic? Just remove all of the rep gained there as well?

Comment: @durron597 The difference between that suggestion and this suggestion is that this would only affect posts that are closed, not on hold, and stay closed. If a question was opened again the rep could be reapplied.

Comment: @KevinBrown yes, I don't see why not. But I'm open to discussion on why those users should get to keep the rep.

Comment: @TinyGiant I only ask because the current policy for deletion is that old, popular questions keep the rep earned (I think?) if they are deleted.

Comment: @KevinBrown If so then there is no reason not to follow the existing policy.

Comment: This one seems like one of the best cases to move towards.

Comment: Are you suggesting that this should be retro-active? Another [rep recalc](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42904/the-global-reputation-recalc-of-march-2010) may cause a panic.

Comment: I think your query is buggy. [This user](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/337295/reputation-i-have-gained-from-answers-to-bad-qestions?UserId=259038) would lose 360k, but he doesn't have 360k - even if you exclude the repcap.

Comment: Here: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/337355/reputation-i-have-gained-from-answers-to-bad-qestions?UserId=259038 - still doesn't take into account the rep cap, but good enough for a napkin estimate. Also, this is a non-starter; [95% of the top 1000 answerers during the past 90 days would lose reputation](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/337344) - such a change would put the drama surrounding The Great Rep Recalc to shame; not only would it remove far more reputation, it would undo the very rep-retention provisions added following fallout from the recalc.

Comment: consider [edit]ing to address concern that many (most? all?) 3K+ users who would lose their rep because of closure would be motivated to vote reopen to regain rep back (no matter how crappy the question is)

Comment: edit in rev 15 looks okay to me. Another thing probably worth addressing is "grandfathered rep" - one that gets preserved upon deletion of the post having score >3 that has been visible for over 60 days. If such a rep becomes removed on a questions that stayed open for over 60 days, people may wonder how this complies with reasoning presented in [Reputation and Historical Archives](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/) (frankly, I'd prefer such a rep to stay, simply to lower the resistance and friction of closures)

Comment: The issue I see here is that the OP talks about high rep users answering questions that should be closed as dupes; with your suggestion these users will still be rewarded for answering questions that they should have cast a closed vote on. Surely this is the type of behavior that should be curbed where possible?

Comment: If this was to happen  I think the question age should also be taken into account and if a question is over a certain age when it is closed the reputation gains are kept.

Comment: @Tanner I disagree with the OP on duplicates but the basic argument should apply to any other closed question. High rep users should know better than to answer bad questions and I can't think of a better way to teach low rep users not to do the same thing than to not reward them for doing it. This will also inadvertently teach them to suggest useful edits to questions and request better clarifications.

Comment: pretty good! both the changes in rev 16 and overall "package" (I re-read twice to make sure). Have to admit, I was rather skeptical that such a radical proposal can be built without breaking important aspects of the system, but it seems that you somehow managed to handle that. Even the really tricky part about reopening looks okay now. Well done

Comment: Your response to "But my answer was really good!" should also include the option of posting the answer on a more deserving question (possibly a newly-asked one) if the existing question cannot be salvaged.

Comment: I am on the fence about this proposal. First, it is a metric to dissuade answering, and answers should be encouraged - so it has a very large negative in place that it needs to overcome. Second, it doesn't seem to apply to many posts - so it serves more as a scare tactic than an actual tool for preventing answers (which, again, we don't want to do). I looked up my stats on your tool and apparently a whopping 640 of my reputation has come from that metric (1.6%) - so it wouldn't affect my fake internet points, but it would affect the mentality of answering questions in an undesirable way.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255805/1026459

Answer (score 27):

I agree it's a problem but I don't think penalties, bans, throttling and restrictions for answering is the way to go.

Most of the problem is the low quality questions that people swarm around, which can be answered with minimal effort and time investment. I don't like the idea of blocking, but if any form of blocking is to be put in place, I'd *personally* prevent people from answering low quality posts for say 5 minutes.

It should be possible to look at the metrics that feed low quality posts into the review system, be they user orientated or based on the content/length of the post.

Using these metric to prevent answers temporarily would introduce a window of time where people can search for a duplicate that would appear in the comments before users have a chance to answer.

If somebody really wants to answer, they can wait 5 minutes. An answer to any half decent question would generally take at least that amount of time to formulate.

Comment: Your suggestion goes contrary to the grace period we currently have on closed questions, with users who started writing an answer before the question was closed still being allowed to post it, sometimes several hours later. That grace period would have to be delayed by five minutes too for your strategy to work at all, and I don't know if the community will accept that.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi couldn't the "add an answer" button simply be disabled to get around this?

Comment: I like the alternative, but I'm not sure timers like these can work that well. What do you think about making the rep from answers on closed questions no longer count to your total?

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm just not sure about taking away reputation in these cases. The duplicate Q&A process would be subjective on the question and answer. Say for example, the closed question had an answer that was actually far more detailed with multiple up votes than the answer on the duplicate post, should a more in depth answer be penalized?

Comment: Proof of concept: a five-minute delay would have allowed me to close [this often-asked question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31430112/464709) before it was answered both by a 170K+ user and a ~5K user.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Another option would be to block votes on answers during those 5 minutes, and lock votes on dupe-closed questions.

Comment: @Cerbrus, that would be too drastic IMHO. After all, although misguided, the answerers did invest time and effort into their answers, so arguably our main rewarding system should still work under these conditions. (On the other hand, I sometimes suspect the number of upvotes on those posts is tied to the fact the question is closed as a duplicate in the first place.)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi that's a great example right there!

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi although, with my suggestion, I'm not sure that question would have qualified as low quality, unless user reputation under a certain level (1000?) could act as an indicator.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi here's my example for the day with a 133k user that holds a gold badge in topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31454672/dynamic-table-name-to-be-passed-in-sql-query. I don't hold a gold badge so I can't close it on my own.

Comment: Who is identifying these "low quality posts"? Perhaps 5 users with close votes could mark a question as low quality some how, with some set of metrics, and then that would prevent other users from answering it.

Comment: @TravisJ SO already identifies the kind of posts I'm talking about to feed in to the review system AFAIK

Comment: FWIW, this was the theory behind keeping questions in triage off the front page. Works well enough for what it does, but would need to apply to /questions and all tag pages by default to make a dent.

Comment: @Tanner How about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31471821/993547)? All answers are from after I closed it with Mjolnir.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I'm aware this won't catch all cases. It's more like [give dupes a chance](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41jbJm0bXUL.jpg).

Comment: I would love to see the 'post answer after closure' window gone.

Comment: @PatrickHofman sorry, I misunderstood your linked post. So with the "no answering" window you would have had that closed before 3 answers were added and 55 total rep was awarded.

Comment: Yes, they were all posted afterwards, so such feature would have prevented those answers. It is very easy to work-around the closing now.

Comment: @PatrickHofman so I guess those guys were typing and had answers in draft while you closed so were still able to post, never actually been in that situation so have not experienced that first hand.

Comment: @Tanner it happens all the time unfortunately.

Comment: Another frustrating case where a gold badge holder answered (with pretty much a copy of my comment) rather than VTC: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31479446/57475

Answer (score 16):

I doubt penalizing users will gain much ground, rather than punishing users for behavior we don't want I think we should reward them for behavior that we do want.

A while back Pëkka had a good idea, [Create CW answer for every "Vote to close as duplicate" vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198958/217863) and [I added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199050/217863):

> We may be able to offer further incentive for users finding dups by
>   allowing the "dup finder" to keep the +15 rep should the possible dup
>   be marked as the accepted answer.

Basically when a user votes to close/flags a question as a duplicate a community wiki answer is created, if that answer is accepted by the OP the dup hunter gets to walk away with 15 rep for their time.

---

[After some comment discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299353/penalty-for-answering-help-vampire-questions/299396?noredirect=1#comment221036_299396) I think adding a caveat that removes rep earned from answers to questions that are closed within X minutes could go a long way to encourage users to flag/vtc rather than posting a quick/dirty answer.

Comment: You would have to offer more rep. Users who choose to answer rather than close as dupe are often rewarded with upvotes *and* acceptance, tallying at worst 25 reputation. So you would have to offer 30 rep at least, which looks way too high.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That's a fair point... Perhaps adding a caveat that answers to questions that are closed within X amount of time will have earned rep revoked would help with that.

Comment: But then we'd have gone full circle -- surely warning about rep revocation counts as *penalizing users*. (Sorry, I don't want to appear too negative here, but I'm afraid there is no simple answer to this problem.)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Again a fair point, but I think there's a subtle difference between being punished for bad behavior and not being rewarded for it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Think of it as adding an incentive for doing the right thing while removing the incentive for doing the wrong thing.

Comment: This is a very good point, and I suspect the crux of this problem -- *not rewarding* should be considered as less hostile than *penalizing*. Alas, since *not rewarding* would go against behavior established for a few years and thus, I'm afraid, considered as "normal" by some, it may be difficult to drive that opinion home. Excellent point anyway.

Comment: Badges for finding dupes would help too I think. Currently none of the SO incentive systems (rep pots, badges, privileges) actually incentivize finding dupes.

Answer (score 7):

I have nowhere near the experience that most of you do on this site (at least as a poster). However, I do have what may be a different background that makes me a bit more sympathetic toward at least some types of low quality questions, and also toward those who answer them.

I am a high school teacher--mostly math and science, but also a basic JavaScript course. The questions I get in person help remind me that many beginners, especially youngsters, don't always ask questions well for reasons others than laziness. They may not really know the terminology for an effective Google search like experienced programmers do. They may have no idea whether the answer to their question is a one step procedure or a very complex one. They may not have the problem solving skills to break a multi-step algorithm into pieces and make a good start themselves. They might even have tried to read something (perhaps even a duplicate question) but just couldn't quite follow it. In some cases, they're just kids who think it would be cool to have a website and don't really know how to start learning the "right" way.

I'm not saying that all low quality questions deserve sympathy. I'm particularly unsympathetic to blatant "Please do my programming homework for me" questions. Lazy professionals who could write a good question, but don't, deserve any sanctions they get. I do, however, think that it's a good thing if newbies--especially youngsters--find SO to be a safe place to learn a little something even if their question asking skills fall well short of professional standards. I can assure you that it doesn't take much unfriendliness to get many youngsters to stop asking questions.

What fraction of the poor questions are written by kids with highly immature skills as opposed to genuinely lazy people? I don't know; maybe some SO veterans have a better idea. Some of the poor questions I read strike me as the sort of thing I could easily see an interested but unskilled kid asking, but I can't know for sure.

I just know that I sometimes like to give the benefit of the doubt and try to teach a little something if I can. Yes, I suppose I could use the rep boost since I'm sitting at 324, but I don't think I'd do it much less if I didn't get rep for it. I would find it pretty disappointing, though, if you actually penalized me for trying to make someone a little better off.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a mentoring site. This has been gone over many times. [Stack Overflow needs mentors](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111397) [The many shades of newbie-ness](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254881) [How to encourage newbie programmers without enabling "hold my hand" comment streams?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255551) The FAQ [What is the proper way to approach so as someone totally new to programming?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572) is also good reading.

Comment: See also the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648) as a resource for these beginners.

Comment: As I ponder more, I feel torn. I've found solutions to dozens of issues on SO over the years (just reading existing posts), and I felt I should give back by answering questions myself. Maybe it's the teacher in me, but helping well-intentioned but unskilled people feeds me more than it drains me. They don't seem like "vampires." However, I want to be a good SO citizen, and if answering their questions really harms the site as a whole, then I would be willing to respect the SO community and stop. I guess I'm still learning the SO culture and will give your concerns serious thought.

Comment: SO is a pretty good place for your students, but only after you finished your job.

Comment: "What fraction of the poor questions are written by kids with highly immature skills as opposed to genuinely lazy people?" - I don't know either, but I don't care. SO is a site for _professional and enthusiast programmers_; it's _not_ a tutorial or mentoring site. There are tons of resources for beginners which they should explore _before_ asking on SO. We expect people to have a minimum amount of knowledge about the basics of programming before asking a question here.

Comment: @I4mpi, you are absolutely right that beginners would be better served elsewhere. But the reality is that as long as search engine results are dominated by SO, they will arrive here in droves. So what experience do we want them to have when they arrive? Might it be constructive to helpfully suggest appropriate sites for beginners on a page shown to new question posters, at least if the tags include topics such as JavaScript, css, etc.? Mentoring clueless kids may not be SO's mission, but isn't it worth some effort to give them something less discouraging than a quickly closed question?

Comment: The first thing they need is to learn how to learn. They must learn how to RTFM, do research and try things out themselves first before asking for help from others. Guiding people is ineffective at the scale of SO.

Comment: I completely agree with this answer, however, I can't think of a way of making beginners feel more welcome without dropping the quality threshold. We cannot just allow low quality questions to exist, and giving them answers just re-enforces them to create more low quality questions. Could we possibly come up with some kind of... resources for beginners page to nudge users who post "low quality questions" toward the resources they need to improve their skills outside of stackoverflow? Some kind of other community tailored toward newbie programmers, possibly hosted by some form of school?

Comment: I liket the idea of a resources for beginners page. If you post a low quality question as a new user, it might link you to that?

Comment: @Josh Caswell the "SO question checklist" you posted is fantastic, but I doubt most new users are going to find it before posting their question. ...unless SO made it so that very low rep users (say, under 25) had to check off each point to say that they did each one before their question was actually posted.  ... hmmm--I kind of like that idea.

Comment: Yeah, I was suggesting it as something DLH could pass on to eir students or others e knows personally, @PhatWrat.

Comment: @DLH: It's a often fine discerment to make, judging whether an asker is helpable within the goals and bounds of this format, especially viewing just one question at a time. If you err a little on the side of "overly helpful" I don't think you'll do any harm; others of us will err on the opposite side, and we'll meet in the middle. Thanks for your consideration of the site as a whole.

Comment: An example of such a community from my previous comment is nodeschool. It's a self-help learning tool that challenges new developers to work through scenarios that build their node.js skillset and introduces them into new ideas and ways of looking at problems and solving problems.

Comment: Actually I think there is a pretty big difference.  A newbie asking a newbie question is quite different from someone who shows up with a task spec and wanting someone to do it for them.

Answer (score 3):

I think this could actually work out, but for users that consistently answer questions that are closed afterwards. It is undesirable that users answers bad questions, as much as it is undesirable that they do so unknowingly or deliberately.

A message informing them that they are incurring on a "potential problem" by answering those questions, since they could be deleted afterwards, may be the first step towards corrective actions. The specific implementation may be open for discussion (% of answers that were closed in X time window, perhaps) along with more definitive actions if warnings are ignored.

I know that this is possibly a re-spin of some "message answerers if the question is closed" FR, but I don't remember where I saw the one that gave interesting ideas.

Comment: idea of a warning looks quite elegant. Corrective action for users who are getting too much warnings can be simple throttling - that is blocking them from answering questions that are 5 (10, 20...) minutes old. That way could sort of level playing field for users voting to close bad questions

Answer (score 2):

Punishment is unlikely to have much positive effect, instead it may deter answerers from providing answers.

*"but but, that's what we want right?"*

No, because the pool of answerers is already small enough, we need to instead motivate these answerers to begin doing more than answering questions; lets get them to start moderating questions too, so that they will see that the question should have been closed instead of answered.

I'm not entirely sure how to accomplish this, however, one thing that seems to motivate lower rep users is gaining reputation, so maybe find some way to incentivize question closure in such a way that it doesn't get overly abused. For example, paying rep for a close vote similar to downvoting, and then getting that rep back plus a little bonus if the question ends up being closed, and losing it again if it then gets reopened. This may be difficult though if deleted questions are eventually hard deleted, not sure if that ever happens. And then there's the fact that close votes now fade away, would you get rep back when it fades away?

I feel part of the disconnect is that they (newer answerers) see all of this negativity involving downvotes and question closures and feel that we're just being mean and negative rather than helpful, and I'm not sure how we can fix that other than through UI changes, making things like votes less dominant on the page.

Comment: I don't however feel question closure should result in a gain of 15-30 rep, 2 should be plenty, along with some badges to persue.

Comment: Heck, i'm sure there's a large pool of users who regularly provide answers that don't even have the close vote privilege yet.  Not much point in providing incentive for them to do something that they can't do. They could flag for closure, but I don't feel that really has much effect (but that may be because i don't use the review tools.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about gamification.  Stack Overflow motivates me by giving me points and tag score.

That these are arbitrary is rather beside the point.

Likewise at least part of my motivation is helping people and solving problems.

Answering even a bad question presses these buttons.  Closing it does not.

Seperately, we have the help vampire question. Who aren't interested in rep but just want to get their job done. So will all shoddy questions "just in case ".

I would like to offer a different option.  Since what we want is good questions and good answers,  maybe we should start deferring rep awards until a question hits a certain score. Scale it by tag activity perhaps, just so quiet tags don't sit idle indefinitely. (And if it gets closed,  before it hits enough votes then no score)

You aren't the penalising bad behaviour, but instead focusing on rewarding the good ones.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the reversal badges. While most are deleted (and it's no loss), there are a few gems deserving every upvote despite the question deserving every downvote too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3905805

Comment: Yes, granted. But realistically, how often does that actually happen,  compared to the rather large amount of places where it doesn't?

Answer (score -1):

SO I ran the little query someone provided.  It looks like I'd lose 1K of my rep from that-  about 3%.  So not a huge amount.  But I can tell you that if I felt I was being punished for helping people (which is the only reason I'm on this site), I would absolutely stop answering.  And I'm a fairly high rep user-  a low rep user would be even more likely to leave.  This idea would cause SO to lose far more than it gains.  Quite frankly, while mildly annoying these questions are not actually a problem in the current system - they're downvoted and closed quickly.  You're trying to fix something that's already handled.

The OP also mentioned duplicates-  I'm not going to check every single question to see if it's a dupe.  After all these years most things are.  I'll do it for the ones that are asked all the time, or that I know have an awesome answer somewhere.  I'm not going to google every question before I answer it - and its not a reasonable expectation that I should.  Especially not for newer users.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the query, it does not include duplicates in the equation as those questions are considered good sign-posts. You have gained [1395 reputation points](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/337355/reputation-i-have-gained-from-answers-to-bad-qestions?userid=1631193) from questions considered not good enough for stackoverflow. The current rooma rules say that if any of the answers to these questions get upvoted or if an answer becomes accepted, then the question will not be automatically deleted...

Comment: However, after suggestions from users here, I've concluded it would be better if this did not affect questions closed prior to the time that it would be instituted. The last question that you posted which matches the criteria [was posted on 2015-04-16](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29687482) three months ago, which was closed as `Too broad`. Can you really tell me that is a good question to answer? If it is not too broad, then you should be able to edit it into shape so you can get your reputation points. If it is too broad then is it really worth keeping around?

Comment: The intention of my suggestion is not to punish users for answering these questions, but to not reward users for answering them and encourage answerers to edit the questions to make them more clear and on-topic for other readers. If a user still wants to be helpful then they are allowed to and not punished for doing so, just not rewarded either.

Comment: Rereading that question-  I amusingly both decided to answer and voted to close it.  Hard to remember 3 months ago, but my thought is the vote to close was due to the fact a full answer on "How to store multi-dimensional data in SQL" was too broad, but the specific question of the 3 level one is well within range and deserving of an answer.  If reasked right now I would do so again.

Comment: So then do you think the question should be reopened? If so then you would be encouraged to vote as such. Questions being unjustly closed for the wrong reason is just as bad as questions not being closed

Comment: Also looking at that specific question again-  I voted to close on the original version.  I think the edited one is good enough, and have voted to reopen.

Comment: I appologize.  For some reason I confused you with the OP- I'm going to delete that comment. And its not so much the loss of my karma that would anger me (I have a ton of it), but if users, especially new ones, see karma coming and going-  they will be pissed.  I would have been.  A lesson learned from gaming-  never take an achievement away from a user.  Games that allowed xp loss and deleveling were roundly hated when there were alternatives that didn't.  It feels like moving backwards, and we will lose good people to it.

Comment: Ok, but would you be ok with not earning rep for questions that were considered not good enough? Would you go back and edit questions to make them on-topic and pay more attention to the questions that you've answered which have been closed? The other query on my suggestion is pretty helpful in identifying and cleaning. I used it to clean up my old answers. And I read the question I mentioned and your answer, voted to open and voted up the answer and the question.

Comment: I haven't edited a question for other than formatting or spelling mistakes ever, so probably not.  At this point in my SO life the karma loss would go missing in the noise.  But now take a new user, who doesn't know or understand all of the various undocumented/semi-documented rules of SO.  All he knows is his karma is appearing then disappearing, or not appearing at all.  At best that's confusing, at worst frustrating.  I think that's bad.

Comment: Although since you're the query expert :)  here's a question for you-  does this even matter?  What percentage of total karma granted is caused by this?  If we're talking 1-2% or even less (which would be my guess)-  would it be worth the extra complexity and confusion?  Is this really a question we need to waste time worrying about?

Comment: Jon skeet has gained approximately 70,000 reputation points from questions like this, not taking into account questions that were posted before their close reason was instituted, but thats not the point (and neither is the point that I'm not actually a query expert) the point is that if you really want to be helpful and not just out for rep, then you can totally go ahead and answer, if not then you would most likely find answers that are more worthy of your time. And as for new users, I'm sure something could be added to the help pages.

Answer (score -4):

Maybe I've been too focused on *punishment*, that I missed an obvious alternative:

**Reward users for casting close-votes.**

When a question is closed that you cast a close-vote on, reward the close-voters with a small amount of rep.

This amount should obviously not be that high that users just blindly closevote everything, but something like `2-5` points could be an option.
(This is a big risk when rewarding close-votes...)

This option rewards desired behavior, without negatively affecting anyone.

Comment: No, we can't do that. We already tried that with badges in the review queues (and +2 rep boni for approved suggested edits) and we ended up with hordes of drones, half of them suggesting crap and the other half approving it. Offering rep for closure would result in a rampage by users indiscriminately closing questions around as fast as they can.

Comment: Even if it's just a measly 1 rep? At least questions will get closed in time then ;-)

Comment: Yup, even a measly 1 rep (look at the mess a measly 2 rep made). The problem is not questions being closed in time, but the *deserving* questions being closed in time :)

Comment: Hm, collateral damage ;-) I didn't think it would attract that many blind votes.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi : It is quite different here. Suggested edits aim at low rep users, whereas voting to close requires 3000 rep. IMHO, flagging for close should still be handled with Deputy and Marshall badges.

Comment: @Serge, it looks like you're implying that 3K+ users will not engage in rep-greedy, ultimately-destructive behavior because they have 3000 rep. Of course, if that were true, then this question would not need to exist in the first place.

Comment: Yea, this question is inspired by a user that has ___way___ more than 3k rep.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That's a little backwards too since there's surely some high rep users that have high rep because they've actively pursued it.

Comment: [Reward finding duplicate questions -- +10 +2 -5](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90620)

Comment: Why not add +1 rep for each question closed, then if it is later reopened **without editing** the user would lose the +1 because obviously the question shouldn't have been closed, otherwise the question obviosly should have been edited and the close vote was correct.

Comment: @TinyGiant then I think the queues would be flooded still. though there might be some justice what occurs if the queues overflow and not enough reviewers want to actually make sure they should or should not be closed?

Comment: @CayceK I think that it would address the queue flooding somewhat, as users would be more determined to get questions closed, so they would actively seek out other users close votes in the chatrooms. I don't think however, that this suggestion would have as positive an effect as [my subsequent suggestion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299433/4639281)

Comment: @TinyGiant I guess it might, but one of those shoot in the dark situations. Could go either way. Overall I agree with your suggestion the most (got my upvote :))

Comment: @CayceK thanks, btw you would only lose [15 Imaginary Internet Points](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/337295/reputation-i-have-gained-from-answers-to-bad-qestions?userid=3547515) if my suggestion gets approved.

Comment: @TinyGiant I know this is not a constructive comment, but if I could vote for your suggestion again I would just because of that query lol

Comment: WE NEED MODERATORS!!!!!