# Should upvotes received for a post that eventually gets closed for being a duplicate be taken away?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

If I want to increase my reputation the easy way, all I need to do is post questions that have been previously asked and have been well received. By the time they are closed as duplicates one would have received a couple of upvotes and maybe an answer or two.

This has potential for abuse. What is being currently done and what can we do better to counter this?

Would it be fair to take away upvotes received for such a post? Is there a limit on how many duplicates per user can be allowed within in a particular time frame, which if violated the user is docked off rep points?

I am not trying to be negative here. I respect the effort and time that people put in to answer a question. I appreciate the work that goes into flagging a post as a duplicate or reviewing such posts.

I just want to know what members of this community think about this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should there be a deterrent for answering obvious duplicate questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions).  Also, related: [Penalty for answering help-vampire questions? Or reward closure?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299353/penalty-for-answering-help-vampire-questions-or-reward-closure)

Comment: Remind me: is this (the fact that this is actually a duplicate Q) actually ironic, or is this just Alanis Morisette ironic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they shouldn't be taken away.  Closing a post as duplicate isn't implying it's a bad post: just that it has an answer already.  It's a useful post, some of the time.  If the post was, separately, viewed as a good/useful post by users, it should remain.

You're viewing 'close as dup' as a bad thing, worth penalizing, or a penalty itself.  In both cases: it's not.  Sure, sometimes duplicates mean 'this person did not search very hard'; but much of the time, duplicates are perfectly fine questions that happen to be solved by another question that wouldn't be easy to find knowing what the user knew.  Those kind of duplicates are good posts, and help the SO mission: they make it more likely that a future-user will find the useful information.

If the post wasn't very useful, well, it shouldn't have received upvotes...

Comment: Wait wait wait, you voted that this question was a duplicate of "Should there be a deterrent for answering obvious duplicate questions?", and then you answered this question.

Comment: @gunr2171 You have the timing reversed, actually... I answered it then someone else found the duplicate.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I saw your previous comment "(the fact that this is actually a duplicate Q)" and assumed. No problem.

Comment: I also like @durron597 's interpretation though :)

Comment: @Joe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1tmkAFb_Os